# How to read phone numbers with full (not only display name) contact data (first-name, last-name, nickname)? on Android

Tags: android, contacts

I want to collect phone numbers from phone with last-name and first-name (for sorting purpose). How can I achieve that in the simplest way? Is it possible with one query?

And I need both versions: for pre 2.0 SDK and later to be compatibile.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#cp

Try this tutorial.. See the android libraries for more functions

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I was asking about. My question was narrowed to specific conditions, I know how to deal with Contacts in general.

Comment: Nobody knows? I will be satisfied with 2.+ version

Comment: android community is pretty lazy here.. try some other Android Forum